# Developing app/game just for retina iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, interface-builder, retina-display

We are developing a game and want to support only retina iPhone devices for it. We have created @2x assets for the retina iPhone. There are a lot of xib files in the game for which we would be using the interface builder heavily.

If we use @2x assets in the interface builder directly, the only content modes we can use are "Scale to fill" or "Aspect Fill". There are cases where we would want to use other content modes like left, top.

One possible solution we could think of is create assets for non-retina iPhone as well just to create the xibs and then remove the non-retina assets before making the final build.

Has anyone run into a similar issue. Is there a better approach towards this?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  Do you want to have different contentModes for different elements?

Comment: Why not just leave the non retina images in place? More compatible devices = more customers.

Comment: I don't know of a better approach. If your resources were bitmaps they would be only 25% of retina-sized resources but I think the ratio will be worsened with a compressed format. Like MDT says, would non-retina support be so bad?

Comment: @MDT - We have seeing that only 7-8% of our users are on older devices iPhone3GS and below and iPad1. These older devices are also a bottleneck for heavy animation. So we wanted to drop these devices and support only iPhone 4 and above, iPad 2 and the New iPad. We dont want to unnecessarily increase the bundle size by keeping the non-retina iPhone assets in the bundle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can name your assets without @2x prefix, and require front-facing camera in AppStore. This funny trick(used by Apple's iPhoto by the way) will ensure, that only retina devices will be able to install your game.

Comment: What about iPad Mini?